# What is the solution for updating query parameters in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having trouble updating the products when changing the query parameter. For example, my link is `http://localhost:5173/?page=2`, then the useProductQuery hook will return the product on page 2 (I wrote API and hook for this and it works properly). However, updating the data still does not work, as shown in the code below

```
 const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState<string | null>(null)
    
    const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(()=>{
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        const page = searchParams.get('page');
        setPageNum(page)
        
    },[location.search])
    
    console.log(pageNum)
    const { isLoading:isPld, isError:isPe, data:productData } = useProductQuery(pageNum)
    const modifiedProductData = productData as IProduct[] ;
    useEffect(() => {
  console.log(productData);
}, [productData]);
```

This is the useProductQuery hook

```
export const useProductQuery = (page?:any) => {
const { data, ...rest } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['PRODUCTS_KEY'],
    queryFn: async () => (await getAll(page)),
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: true
})

return { data, ...rest }
```

}

I tried creating a state and saving the value passed to the `useProductQuery` hook and using `useEffect` to catch the query parameter change event. When this event is caught, it sets the state to a new value, and when there is a new value, it I want my `useProductQuery` hook to run again, thus returning products from another page.

Comment: your code looks good. can you provide a codesandbox or something (stackblitz etc..) that illustrates your bug?

Comment: what does your `useProductQuery` look like?

Comment: does your `console.log(pageNum)` print the expected result?

Comment: Here is my useProductQuery hook "export const useProductQuery = (page?:any) => {
    const { data, ...rest } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['PRODUCTS_KEY'],
        queryFn: async () => (await getAll(page)),
        refetchOnMount: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnReconnect: true
    })
    
    return { data, ...rest }
}"

Comment: console.log(pageNum) does show the correct results as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `page` as part of the key in your `useQuery` call - see the below code for the change you have to make.

```js
export const useProductQuery = (page?:any) => { 
    const { data, ...rest } = useQuery({ 
        queryKey: ['PRODUCTS_KEY', page], // notice the change here!
        // etc.....
```

See [the documentation here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key) for more.

Comment: Thank you sir, it really worked, I really didn't understand React Query very well that's why I got this error

Comment: Sir, what do you think about using useEffect to catch the query parameter value change event like I do? Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: As another previous answer suggested, the useState/useEffect are not needed here, even though, they work! I would suggest simply moving: `const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search); const page = searchParams.get('page');` to the body of your component, and remove the useEffect/useState. Now `page` will replace your `pageNum` state. For more, see https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect